# I am getting Object reference Not set to an instance of an object error in my asp.net mvc aplication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code there Federal_Mandate I am checking weather this MandateType is 1 or 0

if its one I am just converting this as 1 or 0

```
 mandate.Federal_Mandate = collection["MandateType"].ToString().Equals("Federal") ? Convert.ToByte(1) : Convert.ToByte(0);
```

and my datbase Federal_mandate datatype has tiinyint.

is that something doing wrong i am here.. why I am gettting object reference error here?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one of `mandate`, `collection` and `collection["MandateType"]` is null. Set a breakpoint and find out which.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to figure it out but ... couldn't it be cause your collection["MandateType"] is null?

Maybe you can change it to something like this:

```
mandate.Federal_Mandate = (collection["MandateType"] ?? "").ToString().Equals("Federal") ? Convert.ToByte(1) : Convert.ToByte(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your collection to see if its null before calling a method on it:

```
mandate.Federal_Mandate = Convert.ToByte(0);
        if(collection["MandateType"] != null)
        {
            mandate.Federal_Mandate = collection["MandateType"].ToString().Equals("Federal") ? Convert.ToByte(1) : Convert.ToByte(0);
        }
```